# Seaborn lineplot legend not showing correct line colour - plotting two pandas series on one graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot two data sets with Seaborn, this is my code.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

sns.axes_style("ticks")

ss_data = pd.read_csv('A.csv')
ks_data = pd.read_csv('B.csv')

g = sns.lineplot(data=ks_data, x="K", y="pd", dashes=False)
sns.lineplot(data=ss_data, x="K", y="pd", dashes=False)
g.set_xticks(range(0,22,4))
plt.legend(labels=["A", "B"])
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=500)
```

But this is the graph I am getting, as you can see, the legend doesn't correctly show the line colour for B.

[image]

I think it's probably due to the way that I am adding the second lineplot to the graph, but I couldn't make it work any other way.

Comment: Use [option 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/7758804) to create a single dataframe with an identifying column. Use the identifying column for `hue=`. `ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x="K", y="pd", errobar=None, hue='Source')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `label` parameter (passed to [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot)), and no need for `plt.legend()`.

```
sns.lineplot(
    data=ks_data, x="K", y="pd", 
    label='A', errobar=None)
sns.lineplot(
    data=ss_data, x="K", y="pd", 
    label='B', errorbar=None)
```

Importantly, pass `errorbar=None` (or for seaborn versions prior to 0.12.0, `ci=None`), to turn off plotting of the confidence interval.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a `matplotlib` / `seaborn` version issue?
I'm not able to reproduce your graph. With some dummy data I get the expected results:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

sns.axes_style("ticks")

data1 = {"K":[1,5,10,15,20], "pd":[2,10,20,30,40]}
data2 = {"K":[1,5,10,15,20], "pd":[1.5,9,18,16,35]}

ss_data = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
ks_data = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)

g = sns.lineplot(data=ks_data, x="K", y="pd", dashes=False)
sns.lineplot(data=ss_data, x="K", y="pd", dashes=False)
g.set_xticks(range(0,22,4))
plt.legend(labels=["A", "B"])
```

[image]

I have `seaborn == 0.11.2` and `matplotlib==3.5.0`

Comment: Potentially, I am using `seaborn 0.12.2` and `matplotlib 3.6.3`